# iOS CGContextSetRGBFillColor can't work, the color is always black

Tags: ios

I write a child class of CALayer, and rewrite the method:- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx. but CGContextSetRGBFillColor can't work, very badly. help,help!

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    //CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    for (int i = 0; i < pointArray.count-1; i++)
    {
        HQPoint *point = [pointArray objectAtIndex:i];
        HQPoint *pointNext = [pointArray objectAtIndex:i+1];
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, point.piontX, point.piontY);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, pointNext.piontX, pointNext.piontY);
    }
     CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1, 0, 0, 1);
     CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1);

    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    //CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
```

}

Comment: You aren't *filling* anything.  That is why it doesn't work.  You are *stroking*.  There is a distinction between the two.  Actually it does work, you just don't notice it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are stroking the path, not filling it. You want to set the context's stroke color, not the fill color. Use [CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-F17058).

```
 CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1, 0, 0, 1);
```

For reference, here's Apple's documentation on [stroking and filling paths](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-CJBEIHHJ).